# error "Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member..." when moving a func inside extension

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods, inout

I need to move a method for adding and removing a logging view inside an Extension, in order to give it to every controller. to do so I added a inout UIVew parameter to original method, where I used a global var for the view. no I have this error

> Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'containerForLoading'

removing self from `self.containerForLoading` will give error:

> Escaping closure captures 'inout' parameter 'containerForLoading'

inside the animate closure (see the comment)
is all wrong the entire process or I am lost at the last step?

```
extension UIViewController {
        
    func showLoadingView(containerForLoading: inout UIView, uponView: UIView) {
        
           containerForLoading = UIView(frame: uponView.bounds)
           uponView.addSubview(containerForLoading)
           
           containerForLoading.backgroundColor = .white
           containerForLoading.alpha = 0
           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.24) { self.containerForLoading.alpha = 0.8 } //here the error
           let activivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
           containerForLoading.addSubview(activivityIndicator)
           
           activivityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           
           
           NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
               
               activivityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uponView.centerYAnchor),
               activivityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uponView.centerXAnchor)
               
           ])
           
           activivityIndicator.startAnimating()
       }
       
    func removeLoading(containerForLoading: inout UiView, uponView: UIView) {
           
           containerForLoading.removeFromSuperview()
           
       }
    
}
```

this is the code inside the original viewController

using this var

```
var containerForLoading = UIView()
```

called this way when needed

```
self.showLoadingView(uponView: self.view)
```

```
extension ViewController {
    
    func showLoadingView(uponView: UIView) {
        containerForLoading = UIView(frame: uponView.bounds)
        uponView.addSubview(containerForLoading)

        containerForLoading.backgroundColor = .white
        containerForLoading.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.24) { self.containerForLoading.alpha = 0.8 }
        let activivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        containerForLoading.addSubview(activivityIndicator)

        activivityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            activivityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uponView.centerYAnchor),
            activivityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uponView.centerXAnchor)

        ])

        activivityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    func removeLoading(uponView: UIView) {

        containerForLoading.removeFromSuperview()

    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: `self.containerForLoading.alpha` called inside a `extension UIViewController {}`, so it expects it to be a property of `UIViewController`. It isn't the case. What you meant was ` containerForLoading.alpha` since it's the previous variable you want.

Comment: but cannot remove self or I get Escaping closure captures 'inout' parameter 'containerForLoading' erro

Comment: Can you show what your code is like _before_ you put it into an extension?

Comment: updated with old code, basically the same except for inout new parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make `loadingContainerTag` a local variable, and change the parameter name to something else. Then assign to the parameter just after you create the container view:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func showLoadingView(containerForLoadingProperty: inout UIView, uponView: UIView) {
        // local variable!
        let containerForLoading = UIView(frame: uponView.bounds)
        
        // also set property
        containerForLoadingProperty = containerForLoading
        
        uponView.addSubview(containerForLoading)
        containerForLoading.backgroundColor = .white
        containerForLoading.alpha = 0
        
        // no "self."!
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.24) { containerForLoading.alpha = 0.8 }
        // ... everything else is the same
```

`removeLoading` could just have one non-`inout` parameter:

```
func removeLoading(containerForLoadingProperty: UIView) {
    containerForLoadingProperty.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

**But...**

---

It is very weird for a method that shows a loading indicator, to need an `inout` parameter. It shouldn't assign to a special property that the *caller* provides. It should just show the loading indicator!

The purpose of your `containerForLoading` property is so that in `removeLoading`, you know which view to remove. If you don't store the `containerForLoading` view somewhere in a property, you wouldn't know which view to remove, right? Well, we can use the `tag` property of a view to identify views, so you can just make `containerForLoading` a local variable, and later in `removeLoading`, use its tag to find it.

```
extension UIViewController {
    
    static let loadingContainerTag = <a number you like>

    func showLoadingView(uponView: UIView) {
        // local variable!
        let containerForLoading = UIView(frame: uponView.bounds)
        uponView.addSubview(containerForLoading)
        containerForLoading.backgroundColor = .white
        containerForLoading.alpha = 0
        
        // set tag
        containerForLoading.tag = UIViewController.loadingContainerTag
        
        // no "self."!
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.24) { containerForLoading.alpha = 0.8 }
        let activivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        containerForLoading.addSubview(activivityIndicator)
        activivityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            activivityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uponView.centerYAnchor),
            activivityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uponView.centerXAnchor)
        ])
        activivityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }
    func removeLoading(uponView: UIView) {
        // find view with the tag
        uponView.viewWithTag(UIViewController.loadingContainerTag)?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to be working! I'd like to know if the same achievement is possible via protocol extension, is there some problem with stored properties right?

Comment: Yeah, there is no non-hacky way to add stored properties in an extension. If there were, you could add a `UIView` property to store the loading container.